# Is the order fixed when iterate the 'same' lua table with 'pairs' at any time any machine

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm writing a replay module for a game. The whole logic is written with lua. I hope just record the inputs from player and hope the same result will be calculated with the same inputs. I wonder if the order is fixed when iterate the 'same' lua table with 'pairs' at any time any machine. Or it's depend on the key type of the table, say is the table with the table keys OK?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no guarantee on the order of `pairs`. Use an array (table with sequential integer keys) and `ipairs` if you need to guarantee a specific order.

If you're concerned about replays, it shouldn't matter as long as the behavior doesn't change with the order of the items.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Would you please give me more detail about what caused the order changed?